# Crystal Reports - String is non-numeric

Tags: string, crystal-reports, numeric

I have the application running on two computers and one is bringing back the error "The string is non-numeric", while the other runs the report fine.

Both systems are running the same version of the program, running the same report from the same source. What can I do to look for the error, or how can I fix this query?

Version is 2013, support pack 4

Comment: Can you post the contents of the formula causing the error?

Comment: There is the Year_Rolled-1 variable:
tonumber({@Year_rolled})+1999 
and Year_Rolled has a bunch of statements like this:
If totext(CurrentDate) = '2013-02-01' to '2014-01-31' then '13' else

Comment: If totext(CurrentDate) = '2013-02-01' to '2014-01-31' then '13' else ----- what is after the else?

Comment: Just more of those. Goes from 2012 to 2024, then nothing. It ends with: If totext(CurrentDate) = '2024-02-01' to '2025-01-31' then '24'

Comment: It's returning Year_rolled as "", and I'm not sure why. Is it to do with the format of CurrentDate? Is there a way for me to change that?

Comment: It is interesting that it is working one one system and not the other ..tonumber() will not work on alpha characters, blanks, null or special characters. something in the @Year_rolled formula is returning something that cannot be converted to a number

Comment: It's frustrating cause they're both pulling the same thing. We reinstalled on both. The only thing I notice is different is when I go to run the query, it prompts me for month/day/year, and on the other computer it prompts me for day/month/year. But I can't figure out how to change the prompt either.

Comment: Figured it out, wasn't submitting the date info in the right format.